# Magento 2: How to solve the error 500 in Web Setup Wizard when installing Amazon Pay?

Tags: magento2, payment, component-manager, web-setup-wizard

I want to install **Amazon-Pay** in my **Magento 2.1.0**

But I can't open the [**Component Manager**] page.

I got the **500 error** when I opened the page [**Web Setup Wizard**] and click to [**Component Manager**] page.

**Additional information:**

```
RuntimeException

File:
/var/www/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PackagesData.php:88
Message:
Couldn't get available versions for package shockwavemk/magento2-module-mail
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/ComponentGrid.php(98): Magento\Setup\Model\PackagesData->syncPackagesData()
#1 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\ComponentGrid->componentsAction()
#2 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#3 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#4 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

Any ideas? Pls help, thanks!

Comment: It appears that it cannot retrieve the extension magento2-module-mail by shockwavemk. I have no idea what that extension does or the creator but disabling the extension/manually uninstalling it should correct the issue until you can contact the developer for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

this is a known problem with Magento 2.1

you can find a possible solution in this linked comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6718#issuecomment-302527629

which references this change: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/9692/files