# Magento 2: How to solve the error 503 in the Component Manager page?

Tags: magento2, component-manager, web-setup-wizard

I'm trying to install an extension using the Setup Wizard that can be accessed using the route **System > Tools > Web Setup Wizard**, but just the Component Manager page it's not working, after a long period loading I received this page below:

[image: Web Setup Wizard with error 503 in Magento 2]

**Further information**

- In the System Upgrade screen, all the checkpoints are ok.
- My System Configurations page is configured right, using my keys.
- I'm not receiving any error message related to `max_execution_time`
- I've tried to access the URL `mystore.com/setup/index.php/componentGrid/components` but I receive the same error 503.

I've tried these two solutions before:

[I have 500 Internal Server Error in Component Manager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/154602/16416)

[Magento 2: How to solve the error 500 in Web Setup Wizard when installing Amazon Pay?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/190480/16416)

Do you have some idea to try?

Answer (score 0):

First improve your `memory_limit` as well, so remove the third-party module that is set in your **composer.json**.

> Usually you can find into **require** and **repositories** sections!

Then run these commands below in your **root** folder and try again:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento" \
&& composer update -vvv \
&& mage setup:static-content:deploy -f \
&& mage setup:upgrade \
&& mage cache:flush
```

[image: Magento 2 Component Manager Setup]